# How can I make a continuous distribution out of simulation results in R?

Tags: r, distributions, simulation

I have run 10,000 random samples (910 data points each) on a data set of about 75,000 data points. I would like to make a continuous distribution out of this so that I can test the probability of getting the results of a particular non-random sample which I made based on theoretical concerns.

For each random sample (and for the "real" sample), I collected the number of hits, the number of hits + misses (this number varies somewhat for reasons which I don't think are important), and the relative frequency of hits (hits / hits+misses).

Ideally, I'd like to take the relative frequencies and turn it into a continuous distribution (I assume it will be roughly normal), so that I can then see how likely the "real" relative frequency would be (using something simple like a T-test). But I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

On the other hand, is there an easier way to test the probability of obtaining my actual results just given a long file of the results of each random sample?

I assume there's some kind of R function that would make this fairly straightforward. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is a bootstrap simulation in order to estimate the distribution of a statistic (the relative frequencies).

The package I'd suggest you to look into is the [boot package:](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html)

> functions and datasets for
>   bootstrapping from the book "Bootstrap
>   Methods and Their Applications" by A.
>   C. Davison and D. V. Hinkley (1997,
>   CUP).

It should hold many functions needed for what (it seems to me) that you are trying to do.

Here are some [tutorials on the boot package](http://www.r-bloggers.com/bootstrapping-and-the-boot-package-in-r/).

Best,
Tal

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like a [Kernel Density Estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) of the distribution. In R I think you want [density](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/density.html) function.

Comment: Hi John.  I believe he might want it on a bootstrap sample.